# Wrapper for function with variable execute time

Tags: python

I have a function that, depending on the input, can take seconds or days to execute (no set time limit). If the function execution is long running, I need to take certain actions on a regular interval (like recording the log every 5 min). I want to implement a wrapper that does this activity on regular interval but proceed as soon as the function execution completes. Check and sleep does not work for me as I do not want to waste time sleeping even though the function execution is complete.

Comment: What exactly would you be logging from the wrapper every 5min? Having a hard time understanding the user case.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried. You should be able to write a decorator which at least prints a message before your function starts and another after it ends.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution coming to mind is building a decorator where the wrapper starts a [thread](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/), which then logs whatever you wish and you terminate the thread when the execution ends.